# Hi, is there is a better way to wait for an async execution to finish in rust

Tags: rust

Just to explain, I send a command and an id to the other thread, the other thread executes the thing, and return the command and id as a tuple. Because multiple functions might be called at nearly the same time and they are io operations, they might be returned in a different order than they came. So, I have this function to wait for the right return value and put the rest into a map(the variable called results) so that the other functions calling can retrieve theirs as well. However, I think if there is a case of two functions calling this one at the same time, they might be racing to retrieve the value at the channels. I just think there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

For now I have this function to wait for an async execution in another thread:

```
async fn wait_for(&mut self, id : u64) -> (u64, io::Result<SomeResult>) {
        loop {
            let temp = self.channels.1.recv().await.unwrap();
            if temp.0 == id {
                return temp
            } else {
                self.results.insert(temp.0, temp.1);
            }
            if let Some(res) = self.results.remove(&id) {
                return (id, res)
            } 
        }
    }
```

*P.S.* I also had a thought of having another thread do the checking and return the results in order, but that pretty much defeats the purpose of async/await (as far as I know).

Comment: The approach seems quite legit, but I think you need to check whether you have the result before the loop. (And you don't need to do it in the loop, as you'll return the result as soon as you get the correct ID.) Also, you don't need to return the id, as the function receives it already, so the caller knows it. Finally, I'd recommend a bit more use of tuple destructuring and less `.0` and `.1`. For example, the code could look [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6df00c968c42719aa3011eca743be703).

Comment: I think this needs some clarity. For one thing, when running async tasks the executor can usually return a future that will yield the result of that particular task. Perhaps you have reasons for using a channel (only dedicating one thread or processing things in order for example), but I imagine there's better ways of doing what you want, if only we had the whole picture.